# EWS - A token was not recognized in the JSON content

Tags: javascript, json, rest, office365, exchangewebservices

I try to send an email via EWS using Javascript and the REST API.
The OAuth is not the problem so far.
The problem is, if I try to send the email, the Server sends this response:

"{"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content."}"   (taken from Chrome Debug Console).

Here my Javascript, where the error occurs:

```
function mailIsRaus(token) {

    var gottenParam = JSON.stringify(token);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(gottenParam);
    var leToken = jsonObj['access_token'];
    //This is the Token from Active Directory
    leToken = "Bearer " + leToken;

    var Message = {
        "Message": {
            "Subject": "TESTING REST API EWS",
            "Body": {
                "ContentType": "Text",
                "Content": "IT WORKED. The EWS is working my friend."
            },
            "ToRecipients": [
                {
                    "EmailAddress": {
                        "Address": "johndoe@something.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "SaveToSentItems": "true"
    };
    //eMailData = JSON.stringify(eMailData);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", leToken);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        data: Message,
        url: 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail',

        success: function (e) {
            console.log('Email sent');
            console.log(e);
        },
        error: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
}
```

I strictly sticked to MSDN and now, I have no clue, why this error occurs.
If I comment out the "setRequestHeader" I get an error 401 unauthorized.
The token ist correct.
The scope is also correct.

Maybe I made an simple mistake in the "var Massage" or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
I had to uncomment the following line of code to:

```
eMailData = JSON.stringify(eMailData);
```

Now it is working fine.